# valid JS but mouseover not working

Tags: jquery

i'm struggling with the lowly mouseover to change a background image. JSLint is telling me my code is valid but it's still not working. Can you help?

http://jsfiddle.net/kxNvW/23/

html

```
<div class="btn large contempt">


</div>
```

css

```
.btn.large.contempt {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/83c79f/fff);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".btn.large.contempt").bind('mouseover', function() {
$(".btn.large.contempt").attr('background','url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/c78383/fff)');
 });
});
```

Comment: any reason you don't do this with css? `.btn.large.contempt:hover {
    background: url(//dummyimage.com/100x100/c78383/fff);
}`

Comment: @Prescott is that just css then?

Comment: it sure is, much more effective than javascript imo

Comment: @Prescott guess that is the simplest solution but it's good to know the reason why my jquery was wrong anyways. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `attr` with `css` - `background` is a CSS property, not a HTML one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/kxNvW/29/

Comment: Thanks, Amadan answered before you so I have to accept his, but thanks.